# Finding the perfect squares in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help trying to find all of the perfect squares in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$. I have found the squares but I don't know what perfect squares are. I have found the squares to be {0,1,4,9,12,12,10,10,12,3,9,4,1} for $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: So in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, an integer $m$ is a perfect square if there exists an integer $k$ such that
$$k^2 \equiv m \mod n.$$
We call $m$ a quadratic residue modulo $n$.

Comment: You should not repeat.  The (perfect) squares are $0,1,4,9,3,12,10$.

Comment: If your question is about the difference between squares and *perfect* squares, they're the same thing.

Comment: Also, the squares in $\mathbb Z_{13}$ happen to have the nice property that $9 = -4$, $10 = -3$, and $12 = -1$. So, if you wanted to, you could list the squares as $\{0,\pm1,\pm3,\pm4\}$.

Comment: @Théophile It has the property because $13$ is of the form $4k+1$. More generally, $x$ is a quadratic residue mod $p=4k+1$ if and only if $-x$ is.

Comment: In many other languages,e.g. the Nordic ones, the word perfect is just misleading, with its connotation to perfect numbers.